# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user

Tags: sql, sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to Install Microsoft SQL Server and sql server management studio on Ubuntu 16.04, Microsoft SQL Server has been successfully installed but getting this error while installing sql server management studio

Comment: SSMS isn't supported on Linux; it's a WIndows only application. Use ADS (Azure Data Studio).

Comment: Any more info: What username? Are you using SQL Auth or Kerberos? Have you enabled correct permissions? Is DB running in single user mode?